# Swift Stripe Node.js

Tags: node.js, swift

Looking for help on how to pass data from swift file to my node.js firebase function call to stripe. Not experienced with node.js. I am trying to pass my **stripeTotalAmount** to my node.js call that's sent to stripe. If you can explain how data passing works between swift and my node.js file I would greatly appreciate that. Thank you!

**Node.js File**

```
 exports.stripePaymentIntentRequest = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
try {
  let customerId;

  //Gets the customer who's email id matches the one sent by the client
  const customerList = await stripe.customers.list({
      email: req.body.email,
      limit: 1
  });
          
  //Checks the if the customer exists, if not creates a new customer
  if (customerList.data.length !== 0) {
      customerId = customerList.data[0].id;
  }
  else {
      const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
          email: req.body.email
      });
      customerId = customer.data.id;
  }

  //Creates a temporary secret key linked with the customer 
  const ephemeralKey = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
      { customer: customerId },
      { apiVersion: '2022-11-15'}
  );

  //Creates a new payment intent with amount passed in from the client
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: parseInt(req.body.amount),
      currency: 'usd',
      customer: customerId,
      automatic_payment_methods: {
        enabled: true,
      }
  })

  res.status(200).send({
      paymentIntent: paymentIntent.client_secret,
      ephemeralKey: ephemeralKey.secret,
      customer: customerId,
      publishableKey: 'pk_test_51I8zoILw87X7i4vz3Wxu4EAmmNxKKtgKNpwwMwpsbUHZ1Pe8La4CDiVyNao1bYQULFT9mfNV1Ys22PzeyndpWNUP00YIzK6Mji',
      success: true,
  })
  
} catch (error) {
  res.status(404).send({ success: false, error: error.message })
}
});
```

**Swift HTTP Call**

```
func callStripeCheckOut() {
    // MARK: Fetch the PaymentIntent and Customer information from the backend
    let stripeTotalAmount = StripeCart.total
    var request = URLRequest(url: backendCheckoutUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = stripeTotalAmount.description.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(
        with: request,
        completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data,
                  let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                    as? [String: Any],
                  let customerId = json["customer"] as? String,
                  let customerEphemeralKeySecret = json["ephemeralKey"] as? String,
                  let paymentIntentClientSecret = json["paymentIntent"] as? String,
                  let publishableKey = json["publishableKey"] as? String,
                  let self = self
            else {
                // Handle error
                print("Some type of error occured in the call")
                return
            }
            // MARK: Set your Stripe publishable key - this allows the SDK to make requests to Stripe for your account
            STPAPIClient.shared.publishableKey = publishableKey
            // MARK: Create a PaymentSheet instance
            var configuration = PaymentSheet.Configuration()
            configuration.merchantDisplayName = "Example, Inc."
            configuration.applePay = .init(
                merchantId: "com.foo.example", merchantCountryCode: "US")
            configuration.customer = .init(
                id: customerId, ephemeralKeySecret: customerEphemeralKeySecret)
            configuration.returnURL = "payments-example://stripe-redirect"
            // Set allowsDelayedPaymentMethods to true if your business can handle payment methods that complete payment after a delay, like SEPA Debit and Sofort.
            configuration.allowsDelayedPaymentMethods = true
            self.paymentSheet = PaymentSheet(
                paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentClientSecret,
                configuration: configuration)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.checkoutButton.isEnabled = true
            }
        })
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is so much missing to be able to provide any meaningful input but at a simple glance but

```
stripeTotalAmount.description.data(using: .utf8)
```

Should be a JSON

`onCall` functions are also much safer than `onRequest` you calls are completely vulnerable to Man-In-The-Middle attacks right now.

Comment: Thank you for the input I will change it to onRequest because of your security info you provided. What else can I provide for clarity?

Comment: In case anyone is reading this firebase does not allow a onRequest to be changed to a onCall. Must delete function first in console, then deploy firebase functions again in terminal.

Comment: Am I going the right path by using request.httpBody =

Comment: @LukasBimba as long as it is a JSON but with onCall you’ll use a dictionary

Comment: @LukasBimba I should also mention that onCall doesn’t get called with URLSession it uses the “Functions” dependency from Firebase that is why it is safer.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this question and wants to know how to pass data to a Node.js file that is using a firebase function call, like the below answer states you must convert to JSON and how to do so is below... there are other things that must align correctly too but if you see what I do with StripeCart.total just replace that with what data you need in the call

```
let json: [String: Any] = ["amount": StripeCart.total]
    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
    var request = URLRequest(url: backendCheckoutUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("\(String(describing: jsonData?.count))", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = jsonData
```